# view controller's navigation controller property is nil after being pushed

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to understand why a) vc2's navController property is nil, and b) why the nav controller vc stack does not have vc2.

```
import UIKit

let vc1 = UIViewController()

let navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)

print(navController1.viewControllers) // prints vc1
print(vc1.navigationController) // prints navController1

let vc2 = UIViewController()

navController1.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)

print(navController1.viewControllers) // prints only vc1. Hmmm

print(vc2.navigationController) // prints nil
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing...

```
let vc1 = UIViewController()

let navController1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc1)

print(navController1.viewControllers) // prints vc1
print(vc1.navigationController) // prints navController1

let vc2 = UIViewController()

// animated: true !!!!
navController1.pushViewController(vc2, animated: true)

// next two lines execute BEFORE the above line finishes
print(navController1.viewControllers) // prints only vc1. Hmmm

print(vc2.navigationController) // prints nil
```

Change animated to false:

```
// animated: false !!!!
navController1.pushViewController(vc2, animated: false)
```

and you'll see what you were *expecting* to see.